# How to set and get with an array of key values on Firestore + Ionic 4?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I'm trying to set and get some TODO notes, but the problem is i'm sharing it with all the users, and it ISN'T SAVING on my firestore database, don't know why, but it remains. My model is:

[image: screenshot]

and my add and get method is:

```
    idea: Idea = {
    name: '',
    note: '',
    date: new Date().getTime()
};

ADD:
this.afs.collection(`users/${this.user.getUID}/ideas`).add(this.idea)
GET_ALL:
this.afs.collection(`users/${this.user.getUID}/ideas`)
```

I'm doing well my modal? i need to set some Id on every idea? Thank you so much

**UPDATED**:

Now i know how to add it, now just need to know how to pass the position of array i cliked to the details-page to load the detail-idea.

*SOLUTION ADD*:

```
    this.afs.doc(`users/${this.user.getUID()}`).update({
        ideas: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(this.idea)
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FINALLY RESOLVED**

This is my code:

```
# ADD #
this.afs.collection('ideas').add(this.idea)


# LOAD FROM EXISTING IDEA #
ngOnInit() {
    this.ideaId = this.route.snapshot.params['id']
    if (this.ideaId) {
        this.loadIdea();
    }
}

async loadIdea() {

    this.afs.collection<Idea>(`/ideas`)
    .doc<Idea>(this.ideaId)
    .valueChanges()
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.idea = data
        loading.dismiss()
    })
}

# REMOVE #
    remove(idea: firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) {
    firebase.firestore()
    .collection('ideas')
    .doc(idea.id).delete()
    })
}

# GET LIST FROM IDEAS #

    getIdeas(){
    firebase.firestore().collection('ideas')
    .where('owner', '==', this.user.getUID())
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        console.log('querySnapshot: ' + querySnapshot)
        this.ideas = querySnapshot.docs
    })
}
```

[image: MY MODAL]